# how to start docker container from gradle?

Tags: docker, gradle

I am trying to switch from Cmake to gradle. I want to configure gradle to work as follow

```
$ cd myapp && ls myapp
$ Dockerfile build.gradle src 
$ gradle build
```

1. Build the docker image from docker file
2. start container
3. build the application

The  docker image contains complete environment for my app.

```
FROM debian:stretch


RUN  apt-get update -y && apt install -y   git \
      python3-dev libncurses5-dev libxml2-dev \
      libedit-dev swig doxygen graphviz xz-utils ninja-build


RUN echo "deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian stretch main" >> /etc/apt/source.list
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jre openjdk-8-jdk
# Clang 8 as a compiler
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  xz-utils \
  build-essential \
  curl \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
  && curl -SL http://releases.llvm.org/8.0.0/clang+llvm-8.0.0-x86_64-linux-gnu-ubuntu-18.04.tar.xz \
  | tar -xJC . && \
  mv clang+llvm-8.0.0-x86_64-linux-gnu-ubuntu-18.04 clang_8.0.0 && \
  echo 'export PATH=/clang_8.0.0/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc && \
  echo 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/clang_8.0.0/lib:LD_LIBRARY_PATH' >> ~/.bashrc

#
RUN apt-get update
#install sdkman 
RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh
RUN apt-get -qq -y install curl wget unzip zip
RUN curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash
RUN source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"

#install gradle
RUN yes | /bin/bash -l -c 'sdk install gradle 6.1'
```

PS: This is cpp project

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you are asking _what_ to put in your `Dockerfile` to make the above workflow work?

Comment: @Botje Not really, because this workflow should be handled by gradle i guess. But what do u think, how to handle in `Dockerfile`

Comment: I asked because it made more sense to bake Gradle into the container and use that to build, as opposed to writing a Gradle file that only launches `docker`, which is a very roundabout way of writing a shell script.

Comment: Actually my docker file contains everything that project need including gradle. I try to write a script which builded image, run container and lunch `gradle build` command. but this didnot work either.

Comment: Can you add the `Dockerfile` to the question?

Comment: @Botje added to `Dockerfile`

Answer (score 1):

You can build a docker image from Gradle tasks by using `**com.bmuschko:gradle-docker-plugin:3.1.0 plugin`**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
                mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.bmuschko:gradle-docker-plugin:3.1.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.bmuschko.docker-remote-api'

    import com.bmuschko.gradle.docker.tasks.image.Dockerfile
    import com.bmuschko.gradle.docker.tasks.image.DockerBuildImage
    import com.bmuschko.gradle.docker.tasks.image.*

    task buildImage(type: DockerBuildImage) {
            group = ''
            inputDir = file('.')
            tag = 'image name:'+tag
    }
```

read the documentation for more details  https://bmuschko.github.io/gradle-docker-plugin/

Build an image from Gradle task -              **./gradlew taskname**

To start container and run the command inside it you can use **CMD** or **ENTRYPOINT** and specify the command in Dockerfile

CMD ["start.sh"]

in start.sh you can specify your command to be executed after running the container

Comment: No you just need to run the gradle task and it will build the image for you

Answer (score 1):

Let me slightly clean up that Dockerfile first:

```
FROM debian:stretch

RUN echo "deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian stretch main" >> /etc/apt/source.list
RUN apt-get update -y && apt install -qq -y \
      python3-dev libncurses5-dev libxml2-dev \
      libedit-dev swig doxygen graphviz xz-utils ninja-build \
      openjdk-8-jre openjdk-8-jdk \ 
      xz-utils curl git build-essential wget unzip zip

# Clang 8 as a compiler
RUN curl -SL http://releases.llvm.org/8.0.0/clang+llvm-8.0.0-x86_64-linux-gnu-ubuntu-18.04.tar.xz \
  | tar -xJC . && \
  mv clang+llvm-8.0.0-x86_64-linux-gnu-ubuntu-18.04 clang_8.0.0 && \
  echo 'export PATH=/clang_8.0.0/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc && \
  echo 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/clang_8.0.0/lib:LD_LIBRARY_PATH' >> ~/.bashrc

#install sdkman 
RUN ln -fs /bin/bash /bin/sh
RUN curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash
RUN source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
RUN yes | /bin/bash -l -c 'sdk install gradle 6.1'

RUN mkdir /src /work
WORKDIR /src
ENTRYPOINT gradle build -p /src
```

The important bits are at the bottom: it creates a `/src` directory and executes `gradle build` there. All that remains for you is to make that directory available when you build.

Assuming you built the container once with `docker build -t my-build-container .`, you can run it as follows:

```
docker run -v $(pwd):/src my-build-container
```

Depending on your build system, this might pollute your source tree with various build artifacts owned by root. If so, consider switching to out-of-tree builds by changing the default working directory to `/work` instead. All build results will go to `/work`, and you can extract them from the container afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Add docker plugin first

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath("se.transmode.gradle:gradle-docker:1.2")
    }
}
```

create simple task like this in build.gradle file

```
task buildDocker(type: Docker, dependsOn: build) {
    push = false
    project.group = 'testProject'
    project.archivesBaseName = jar.baseName
    applicationName = jar.baseName
    dockerfile = file('src/main/docker/Dockerfile')
    doFirst {
        copy {
            from jar
            into stageDir
        }
    }
}
```